# mysql deadlocking with autocommit on and no confict

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks

I have a piece of (Perl) code, of which I have multiple instances running at the same time, all with a different - unique - value for a variable `$dsID`. Nearly all of them keep falling over when they try to execute the following (prepared) SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM ssRates WHERE ssID IN (SELECT id FROM snapshots WHERE dsID=?)
```

returning the error:

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Which sounds clear enough, except for a few things.

1. I have autocommit enabled, and am not using (explicit) transactions.
2. I'm using InnoDB which is supposed to use row-level locking.
3. The argument passed as `$dsID` is unique to each code, so there should be no conflicting locks to get into deadlocks.
4. Actually, at present, there are no rows that match the inner `SELECT` clause (I have verified this).

Given these things, I cannot understand why I am getting lock problems -- no locks should be waiting on each other, and there is no scope for deadlocks! (Note, though, that the same script later on does insert into the `ssRates` table, so some instances of the code may be doing that).

Having googled around a little, this looks like it may be a "gap locking" phenomenon, but I'm not entirely sure why, and more to the point, I'm not sure what the right solution is. I have some possible workarounds, -- the obvious one being to split the process up: do the `select` clause, and then loop over results giving `delete` command. But really, I'd like to understand this otherwise I'm going to end up in this mess again!

So I have two questions for you friendly experts.

1. Is this a gap-locking thing?
2. If not - what is it? If yes -- why. I can't see how this condition matches the gap lock definition.

(NB, server is running MariaDB: 5.5.68-MariaDB; in case this is something fixed in newer versions).

Comment: As I know there are some bugs that is related to your topic. I have encountered similar issue with Maria DB but we were using pessimistic lock. As I understand from your description there is not any lock mechnaism

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez - correct - I am not doing any explicitly locking.